# How to use Specflow srsprofile in mstest runsettings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, specflow, runsettings

One of my projects uses spec flow + MSTest + MSBuildGeneration tool. I have few filter tags defined in my srsprofile and created a runsettings file something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <!--<ResultsDirectory>..\..\..\Reports\LastRun\</ResultsDirectory>-->

    <!-- [x86] | x64  
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>

    <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework46</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>

  <!-- test adapter -->
  <MsTest>
    <Profile>sample.srprofile</Profile>
  </MsTest>
</RunSettings>
```

UnitTest Provider

```
  <specFlow>
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="MyProject.Steps" />
    </stepAssemblies>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  </specFlow>
```

Since I am using MSTest and not SpecRun, the adapter I believe should be MsTest, but the tests are not showing up in the test explorer in visual studio 2017 for the defined filters. am I doing it wrong ? Is there a different way to use filter tags in srsprofile for mstest ?

Comment: Are specFlow tests showing up at all, or are they just now showing up under the specified filters?

Comment: SpecFlow tests are showing up without any testsettings or runsettings. But I don't want to run all the filter tags at once, I want to control it and I believe this will be accomplished via runsettings file where you provide a path for srprofile in which you define your filters but I just don't know a way to use it with MsTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `srProfile`- File is a feature of the SpecFlow+ Runner (aka SpecRun). The features of it are only available there. You can't use it with MSTest.

As far as I found out, there is no way to set filter in the runsettings file at all.

Docs for it are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019

---

Full disclosure: I am the community manager of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: ah! too bad, I might try switching it to SpecRun, Thanks Andreas